# JQuery statement work only after the alert inside success function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I put an alert after `$('#add_new').trigger('click');` the statements below it works fine but when the alert is removed the statements below it doesn't work. I think its because the trigger event was not completed before the statements below was executed.
 Im new to Jquery , can anyone help?  Thanks.

```
function addCourseMember(){
    var benId = $('#courseBenId').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'${createLink(controller: 'classCourseCalendar',action: 'getBenMemberDetails')}',
        data:{benId:benId},
        type:'POST',
        async:false,
        success:function(data){
            $('#add_new').trigger('click');
            $("#firstName").val(data.firstName);
            $("#lastName").val(data.lastName);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: If the `#add_new`'s click handler reads the value of the `#firstName` element you should  move to `trigger` statement to the end of the callback.

Comment: @Vohuman Why what's wrong in that? Mr.OP can you show the click event associated with that element?

Comment: @Vohuman I did move it at  the end, but wasnt working.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please provide more context.

Comment: Try to print or check the data.firstName and data.lastName [check in console]. I assume data is not available [still data didn't download].

Comment: @MuraliMohan No, the callback is called when the request is complete.

Comment: Yes. A fiddle or pen will help in understanding the issue. Saurav, did u create any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saurav, ajaxComplete will work but it would be better to use setTimeOut(say to minimal time -  1 second) to hold until your trigger completes.

Comment: Yes, ajaxComplete did cause problems since it was evoked several times and adding setTimeout worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

Adding **ajaxComplete** worked for me. Thanks.

```
    function addCourseMember(){

    var benId = $('#courseBenId').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'${createLink(controller: 'classCourseCalendar',action: 'getBenMemberDetails')}',
        data:{benId:benId},
        type:'POST',
        async:false,
        success:function(data){
            $('#add_new').trigger('click');
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
                $("#firstName").val(data.firstName);
                $("#lastName").val(data.lastName);
            })
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: Note that you will add another `ajaxComplete` event handler every time that you call the function, and that *all* AJAX calls in the page from that point will also call those event handlers.